# Spring cloud Gateway add header, using responde WebClient

Tags: mono, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-cloud-gateway

I`m developing a gateway with spring cloud, I need intercept the request consuming an Oauth then get the response and add header with jwt value (response of Ouath)

[image]

My filter code:

```
@Autowired
private IConsumoInstrospectService consumoIntrospect;

@Override
public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {

    Mono<ResponseIntrospectDTO> rep = consumoIntrospect
            .callInstrospect("firmaCnLlavePrivada", "getAccessToken()","getScope()", "IN");
    // How Can I get the value?
    String token=rep.block().getJwt();
    
    //String token="x";
    
    log.info("token "+token);
    String authHeader = "Bearer " +token ;

    ServerHttpRequest mutatedRequest = exchange.getRequest().mutate().header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, authHeader)
            .build();
    exchange = exchange.mutate().request(mutatedRequest).build();
    return chain.filter(exchange);
}
```

My service:

```
@Value("${endPoint}")
private String endPoint;

@Bean
public WebClient getWebClient() {
    return WebClient.builder().build();
}

@Override
public Mono<ResponseIntrospectDTO> callInstrospect(String Jwt, String AccessToken, String Scope, String tipoAccessToken) {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Content_Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    headers.add(AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer " + Jwt);
    headers.add("need-jwt", "yes");

    LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String> body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
    body.add("token", AccessToken);
    body.add("token_type_hint", "access_token");
    body.add("iss", Scope);

    Mono<ResponseIntrospectDTO> respService= getWebClient().post()
            .uri(endPoint)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .body(BodyInserters.fromFormData(body))
            .headers(x -> x.addAll(headers))
            .acceptCharset(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(ResponseIntrospectDTO.class);
    return respService;
}
```

[full code Gitlab](https://gitlab.com/omarbarreravalentin/gtw-webflux)

Error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread reactor-http-nio-3

when i use String token=rep.block().getJwt();

Comment: I think you are looking for TokenRelayGatewayFilterFactory ref: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Greenwich.RELEASE/multi/multi__more_detail.html

Answer (score 0):

Reactor doesn't allow to use `block` in `parallel` scheduler. Try to make your code reactive.

Here is an example of extracting attributes from the auth token in filter and adding it to the header

```
   @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {
        return ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                .filter(c -> c.getAuthentication() != null)
                .flatMap(c -> {
                    JwtAuthenticationToken jwt = (JwtAuthenticationToken) c.getAuthentication();

                    String tokenTenant = (String) jwt.getTokenAttributes().get("tenant");
                    if (Strings.isNullOrEmpty(tokenTenant)) {
                        return Mono.error(
                                new AccessDeniedException("Invalid token. Tenant is not present in token.")
                        );
                    }

                    ServerHttpRequest request = exchange.getRequest().mutate()
                            .header("x-tenant", tokenTenant).build();

                    return chain.filter(exchange.mutate().request(request).build());
                })
                .switchIfEmpty(chain.filter(exchange));
    }
```